# Concatenate where queries with or operator in a QueryBuilder

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

QueryBuilder is defined in Microsoft.Windows.Data.DomainServices.
It allows you to create a Query on a collection of type T and apply it later.

When I need to concatenate where queries by && it is easy, for example you can do

```
        var query = new QueryBuilder<Customer>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CustomerFirstName))
            query = query.Where(c => c.FirstName == this.CustomerFirstName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CustomerLastName))
            query = query.Where(c => c.LastName == this.CustomerLastName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CustomerPhone))
            query = query.Where(c => c.Phone == this.CustomerPhone);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CustomerMail))
            query = query.Where(c => c.Mail == this.CustomerMail);
```

I can't find out how should I concatenate those Where queries by || (or)??

I have a query that loads all Products in a database, since products are organized by category and a user can select only a sub-set of categories (the one he is interested in)
I would like to load only products in categories that the user has specified

I know I could do it concatenating Where() by && where I exclude unselected categories
example

```
 query.Where(c => c.CategoryName != "MyCategory");
```

but I don't like it.

I would like to do it in a foreach loop

```
private void LoadProducts()
{
     var query = new QueryBuilder<Product>();

     //Get Only Products in specified categories
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(WebContext.Current.User.SelectedCategoriesCSV))
     {

         foreach (string cat in WebContext.Current.User.SelectedCategoriesCSV.Split(';'))
         {
               ????//query.Where(c => c.CategoryName == cat || );
         }

     }

 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically build your *where* expression and then pass it once to the query.Where(). Check out the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) that provides Or method to accomplish that. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, it seems the PredicateBuilder doesn't work on SL4, I'm using ria services

Comment: I see.. well, you could then try manually building the Or expressions - [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx), and also this [Building LINQ Queries at Runtime in C#](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx)

Comment: the problem here is that the query needs to be serialized and sent to the server... I'm seeing that you can't go far from Where() Take() and Skip()... thanks for your suggestions, I'm trying to understend if those fits

Comment: I haven't tried it, but any reason the PredicateBuilder in source form won't work in SL4?  Nothing jumps out at me as lacking from the SL4 framework.

Comment: I tried to bring it down by nuget and it failed... Anyway I don't think that a query built in such a way will cross the boundaries

Comment: I'm pretty sure passing a query built with the predicate builder would work just fine. It's at least worth pulling the source down and trying to build it under Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic LINQ operator that are available at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb330936.aspx
(download the c# example and get the code in the \LinqSamples\DynamicQuery directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PredicateBuilder` class developed by **Monty’s Gush**.

Try [this](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).